# SQL Conditional Multiplication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in T-SQL (SQL Server 2016), that looks like the following:

```
   Flag       Col 1       Col 2    Col 3        
-----------  ---------   -------  -------
   0           33.1        3.9      5.5
   1           20.5        8.1      4.3
   0           15.3        8.33     1.1
   1           12.1        8.4      9.2
```

This is just a sample of course. But, what I would like to do is update these columns such that if flag = 0, then col 1 stays the same, but col 2 and col 3 = 0. If flag = 1, then col 1 = 0, and col 2 and col 3 stay the same, and so on.

How could one accomplish this in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table SET 
[Col 1] = CASE WHEN [Flag] = 0 THEN [Col 1] ELSE 0 END, 
[Col 2] = CASE WHEN [Flag] = 1 THEN [Col 2] ELSE 0 END , 
[Col 3] = CASE WHEN [Flag] = 1 THEN [Col 3] ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: LOL. Fingers of fury ;)   JK

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Flag` only has values `0` or `1`:

```
update ThyTable
  set Col1 = Col1 * ( 1 - Flag ), Col2 = Col2 * Flag, Col3 = Col3 * Flag
```